# Performing full-text content search with OpenText eDOCS DM

Tags: c#, opentext

How can I perform a document full-text search using Hummingbird DM PCDClient in C#?

I have tried to use following API helper to perform searches: https://github.com/dotnetnick/edocs. Classes DMSearch and DMSql could be able to do this, but I can't figure out correct search criteria and search object keywords for document content searching. I'm only able to search from document profile fields but not from document content.

The content search is demonstrated in OpenText eDocs training video by using DM Extension GUI: https://youtu.be/cVFJaoLhtS4?t=372.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple months of searching I have finally found the correct keywords. The PropertyNames are FULLTEXT_PROFILE, FULLTEXT_CONTENT and FULLTEXT_CONTENT_PROFILE.